# How do i write an amazing love letter?

Tags: creative-writing, style

My protagonist is a normal SLAVE kid. He lives in a kingdom in a fantasy medieval world.

He is in love with a kitsune, so he is going to write a loveletter. He loves her tail, pale skin and emerald eyes and long fluffy ears.

Using the description of this female kitsune, my question is, how do i write a good love letter? What style should i use?

Comment: I've read some of the love letters that my father wrote about my mother. They were not about her physical attributes, but they did communicate the depth of his passion. These were letters written to his sister, and he opened up to his sister in an amazing way, basically saying that he adored my mother, worshipped the ground she walked on, and could never hope to find anyone better. Only he said it through metaphor.

Comment: Does he love anything about *her*, or just the skin she's wrapped in?

Comment: The fact that you specify your kid is a "slave" should be meaningful. Why is he a slave? Is there a class clash in your world? What is his education? Is he literate or illiterate? Who is the "kitsune" he loves? From the same class? From his captors? A slave like himself? All of this is relevant to decide what he's going to write.

Comment: This is bordering on "what to write," because you're asking how Your Character A would write a love letter to Your Character B in a defined setting. "How to write a love letter" without specifying so much about your particular story is more on-topic. Separately, all three items you've noted in your story are clichés. "Slave, kitsune, fantasy kingdom" are very generic. If you work on making your characters and settings unique to your story, then it may become more obvious why A loves B and what he can write about.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Yes its generic,Im working on a story for rpg maker.

Comment: Do you have specific concerns or effects you hope to achieve? Or is the real question here, "how do I write in the style of a character in a book?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There are several approaches and it seems more than one is needed here.*

I'd recommend reading up on writings by and about (ex)slaves in order to get a grip on what that does to a person. Mark Twain may provide an entry point but it is a world in itself.

Early medieval ballads should be a good source on the love-life experience lacking our modern trappings like information overflow, easy travelling, the internet and especially Stack Exchange.

More specifically Japanese literature should give some insight in kitsune, how they lured men and how they made themselves irresistible.

But in the end only *you* can provide the correct taste of the fantasy they're in and the special and individual traits that make THIS a potential couple.

Oh and it should be *really short*:
You hero has no time, energy OR paper to indulge. He is property and will be working long hours.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions.

The first is for the protagonist to find some reason to love the kitsune other than her appearance or some task she might do that the protagonist appreciates or admires. People often want to be loved for who they are, not because they make you breakfast every morning, have the fastest time in the hundred yard dash, or because their hairstyle is flawless.

This is a tough ask. You'll have to think about it.

Try not to use a laundry list such as, "I love you because A, B, and C," where A, B, and C are "you walk the dog when I get home late from work," "you know just how I like my tacos when we go to that Mexican place on 7th street," and "your thesis on snail darters was the best I've ever read."

Instead say things like, "I love you because of who you are. When we lay together on the beach last night,  the stars and the moon shone brighter in the sky then they ever had before, and I felt peace in my heart knowing you were there."

The second suggestion is remember that letters are physical things, not just words. Material touches matter in a letter, such as the color and quality of the pen used (and maybe a second special pen just for a flourish on the signature), the quality of the penmanship, stickers and little drawings in the margins of the letters, dried flowers dropped in the envelope, and so on. Don't miss an opportunity to make the letter more meaningful by including physical touches important to the sender and recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind you are not writing an actual love letter, which properly speaking, has an audience of only one person, and should be tailored directly for that person.  Instead, you are writing a story featuring a love letter, and so that letter, like everything else in your story, should serve your aims as an author in communicating with your audience.

For that reason, there is no one answer.  Is the letter supposed to tell the audience about the character and his life, and the social context he lives in?  Or communicate information about his beloved, instead?  Is it advancing their relationship, or betraying storms to come?  Or is it designed to make us, the readers, fall in love with the character ourselves?  Finally, is it just meant to be admired, as a pure work of art within the larger story?  Each purpose defines a different set of choices.